# cant connect php with ms access database on linux

Tags: php, unixodbc

I have install `unixodbc` and `libodbc` in `ubuntu 14.0` and configured it here is the configuration

```
/etc/odc.ini 
[MyDriver]
Description = MyDriver Driver for MyDBMS
Driver      = /path/to/libmyodbc.so
Setup       = /path/to/libmyodbcs.so
FileUsage   = 1
UsageCount  = 1
```

and data source configuration

```
[MyDataSource]
Description = The Source of My Data
Driver      = MyDriver
ServerName  = localhost
Database    = MyDatabase
UserName    = admin
Password    = something
```

and here is the php code

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable';
$mdb_file = '/path/to/example.mdb';
$uname = explode(" ",php_uname());
$os = $uname[0];
switch ($os){
  case 'Windows':
    $driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}';
    break;
  case 'Linux':
    $driver = 'MDBTools';
    break;
  default:
    exit("Don't know about this OS");
}
$dataSourceName = "odbc:Driver=$driver;DBQ=$mdb_file;";
$connection = new \PDO($dataSourceName,'','');
$result = $connection->query($query)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

But it through access denied for user root then if i enter username of sql 
   it connect with sql

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$dataSourceName = "odbc:Driver=$driver;DBQ=$mdb_file;";
```

To

```
$dataSourceName = "odbc:Driver=$driver;DBQ=$mdb_file;Uid='';Pwd='';";
```

Comment: I do but it just connect with mysql database not with ms access although my dsn refer to ms access file